# Comparing two files lines with same number

Tags: c#, file, comparison

I have two files: file1.txt and file2.txt

file1.txt content

```
this is line 1

this is line 1

this is line 3
```

file2.txt content

```
this is line 1

this is line 2

this is line 4
```

What I want to do is compare line 1 from file1.txt with line 1 from file2.txt and so on. If a two lines is different than just echo the line from file2.txt

This is my code so far.

```
int line_number = 0;
string line_file1, line_file2;

System.IO.StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader("file2.txt");
System.IO.StreamReader file1 = new System.IO.StreamReader("file1.txt");

while (((line_file2 = file2.ReadLine()) != null) && ((line_file1 = file1.ReadLine()) != null))
{
    if (line_file2 != line_file1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line_file2);
    }
    line_number++;
}

file2.Close();
file1.Close();
```

This outputs:

```
this is line 2

this is line 4
```

Please let me know if you know a solution or a better way.

Comment: And what is the problem with the solution that you have?  Your readers should really be in a `using`, but other than that it looks fine.

Comment: Really compare line 1 from File1 with line 2 from File2. Isn't it rather compare line 1 from File1 with line 1 from File2?

Comment: "line 1 from file1.txt with line 2 from file2.txt" - did you mean line 2 from file2.txt, or did you intend to say line 1 on both sides?

Comment: Also what are you using line_number for?

Comment: What's the output of this? I don't see anything wrong. Since a `Stream Reader` uses the interface `IDisposable` you should wrap it in a `using` statement.

Comment: Yes, sorry, edited. line 1 from file1.txt with line 1 from file2.txt and so on. My code works, but I find it ... big and ugly :D. Thought there is a cleaner way

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there isn't a problem with the code; it is working as expected.  Consider posting on Code Review if you simply want to review working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to compare 1st line of file1 with 1st line of file2 and so on.

You can use `File.ReadAllLines()` method to read all lines from the given path.

Try This:

```
using System.IO; //import this namespace. 


String[] strFile1 = File.ReadAllLines("file1.txt");
String[] strFile2 = File.ReadAllLines("file2.txt");

if (strFile1.Length == strFile2.Length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strFile1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (strFile1[i] != strFile2[i])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(strFile2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, awsum! Thanks

Comment: This code is *worse* than the OP's.  The OP's code streams through the files and so has a minimal memory footprint.  This eagerly loads the entire file's contents into memory, which for large files, could be an issue.  There is also nothing *advantageous* about this solution.

Comment: Hi Servy, never tought of that, thanks :)

Comment: @Servy: yes you are right .